# Creating a reverse order list using while loop - unexpected results

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, while-loop, reverse

I am a student in an intro-level python class, and my task is to define "reverse(mylist)" using while loop

This is what I have so far:

```
def reverse(mylist):
    a=0
    b=len(mylist)
    xlist=mylist
    while(a!=b):
        mylist[a]=xlist[(-a)-1]
        a+=1
    return mylist
```

Let's say the input list is [1,2,3,4,5,6], and using my reverse function I will get the output [6, 5, 4, 4, 5, 6]... And [1,2,3,4,5] will become [5,4,3,4,5]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Could you fix your indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following statement makes both `xlist`, `mylist` reference same list object:

```
xlist = mylist
```

You need to copy it.

```
xlist = mylist[:]
```

BTW, using `for` loop, you don't need to increment `a` manually:

```
for a in range(len(mylist)):
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse(mylist):
  a=0
  b=len(mylist)
  xlist=[]
  while(a!=b):
    mylist[a:a]=xlist[(-a)-1]
    a+=1
  return mylist
```

list is transfered by referance not by value.
you need to create new list.
"xlist = mylist" only create a referance.

ps
"for in" is more commonly used in python.

```
for i in range(2, -1, -1):
  xlist.append(mylist[i])

or:

xlist = [mylist[i], for i in range(2, -1, -1) ]
```